# mysql deadlock - why when using different foreign key in update?

Tags: mysql

I am using an innodb database. I have mysql updates such as

```
update my_table set type = 1 where content_id = 1;
```

content_id is a foreign key.

I also have more complicated queries that all use content_id. I have several processes/connections that run the queries, but each with their own unique content_id.

I am seeing a lot of

```
Deadlock found when trying to get lock; try restarting transaction
```

which I don't understand. I thought that the queries would all be independent since they utilize a different foreign key, which will have an index on it. Hence it does not need to scan/lock other row. Is this thinking wrong or could it be because the queries aren't utilizing the index?

Comment: Which storage-engine are you using? If MyISAM - then remember, that it supports only exclusive block mode (i.e. block of all table rows). Or you mean `foreign key` literally - i.e that could by only InnoDB?

Comment: innodb. Updated question.

Comment: Did you tried this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-deadlocks.html ?

Comment: Yes, I tried "Add well-chosen indexes to your tables". And now I'm confused about why that isn't working.

Comment: `Use SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS to determine the cause of the latest deadlock. That can help you to tune your application to avoid deadlocks.`